# Finding all dates of particular dataset in Open Data Cube

Tags: open-data-cube

I am trying to find all dates of a particular dataset in Open Data Cube.

The closest function I could find was `dc.index.datasets.get_product_time_bounds` but that only provides the first and last date.

Is there any way to get all dates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only need the list of dates, you can use [`index.search_returning()`](https://datacube-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/api/generate/datacube.index._datasets.DatasetResource.search_returning.html#datacube.index._datasets.DatasetResource.search_returning), which is *much* faster than a normal search as it doesn't need to pull the entire dataset back.

You give it the list of fields you want returned from the search, and it will return them as tuples:

```py
for [time] in dc.index.datasets.search_returning(
                 ['time'], 
                 product='ls8_nbar_albers', 
                 **other_search_params)
):
   print(time)
   # Time is actually a range
   start_time, end_time = time.lower, time.upper
```

Comment: The last line `start_time, end_time = time` does not work and gives this error: `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable DateTimeTZRange object`

Comment: You can use `time.lower` and `time.upper`.

Answer (score 3):

If what I'm hearing is that you'd like to know all the dates that a datacube product has datasets for, I don't think there's a built-in function.

The naive way to do it is to write something like:

```
import datacube
dc = datacube.Datacube()

datasets = dc.find_datasets(product="prod_name")

# Code to iterate through all datasets goes here
```

Note that this will load all datasets into memory, though. Better would be performing the query on the database. But unless someone else has a better idea, these two will work.